# How can I separate (split) a string in Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

How can I separate (split) a string in Titanium?

I have a Variable like:

```
var abc = '123,123,59785,65.66666,56582.55';
```

I want to change in this format:

```
var x = 123;
y = 123;
z = 59785;
xx = 65.66666;
yy = 56582.55;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `split()`. try this :-

```
var str="123,123,59785,65.66666,56582.55";
var arry = [];

arry = str.split(",");

for(int i = 0; i < arry.length; i++)
     alert(arry[i]);
```